# Attach a delegate as a TreeNode's tag object

Tags: c#, .net, casting, delegates, treeview

Here is my delegate

```
public delegate string filterHandler(TreeNode node);
```

Then in InitializeComponent(), I tried to assign it like this:

```
treeNode7.Tag = new filterHandler(loanAmount);
```

This appears to work, but when I try to call it:

> Error  2   Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode.Tag' cannot be used like a method.  G:\Dropbox\School Assignments\CSCD 371\Final\Final\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database.cs 116 29  StratGen

Also, the Designer is freaking out:

> Message    1   Could not find type 'LCStratGen.MainWindow+filterHandler'.  Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.  If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.  G:\Dropbox\School Assignments\CSCD 371\Final\Final\WindowsFormsApplication1\MainWindow.Designer.cs  81  0

How can I get this working?

Thanks bunches :)

Comment: Move the code from Designer.cs away, put that in constructor after `InitializeComponent();` and check

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, so that did work to assign the delegate. Now, how can I cast the Tag Object into a delegate so it is invocable?

Comment: Okay, I was able to get it:
    
    where.Add( ((filterHandler)n.Tag)(n) );

Comment: Show the code you use to call it (that's where the error is occurring ;-) ) so that we can help. 

To call it you would have to cast the tag to filterHandler before calling it. 

More important, a delegate is a reference to a method that matches the signature of the delegate.